# Defining task in maven archetype to be executed during project creation

Tags: java, maven, ant, maven-archetype

I have a custom maven archetype for creating projects. My questions is, as we define ant tasks to be run during various life cycle phases of a maven project. Is it possible for me to run a task when the project is being generated using my archetype. There is a certain file that I want to execute during project generation which will further copy files to my project's `webapp` folder. Is it possible to define such a task in maven archetype for creation phase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While generating your archetype you can specify which goals of the project to run directly after the archetype generation with `-Dgoals=plugin:goal` as written [here](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#goals)

So having the project pom with something the like of:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>tt</id>
                <phase>run</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echo>${PATH}=${env.PATH}</echo>
                        <echo>Users Home Directory: ${user.home}</echo>
                        <echo>Projects Base Director: ${basedir}</echo>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

And calling `mvn archetype:generate -Dgoals=antrun:run` should allow you to run directly after generation the `antrun:run` goal, and execute whatever script you need.

Comment: I have tried it, but it says `No Ant target defined - skipped`. I am looking into the problem. But I wanted to know how can we pass the `-Dgoals=antrun:run` when creating project in eclipse.

Comment: I think your best bet in that case is to use the external tools configuration, it's not exactly the same, but I believe this article sums it up: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-an-archetype-create-from-eclipse.html